# Java Library to fetch User Details from SharePoint User Profiles

Tags: office365apis, java-api, automation-testing

I am trying to perform automation testing on a SharePoint add-in which has the same functionality as of a Staff Directory.

I am using TestNG Framework on Selenium Tool with Java Language.

For testing, I need to fetch all the User Profiles properties with the users and need to compare if correct data are being displayed on the app.

But the problem here is that I am unable to fetch the user profile properties as I need to create an Authenticator. But I don't have any Client ID and Client Secret for authentication, I am unable to fetch the SP User Profiles data.

As we have Microsoft.SharePoint.Client for C# using which we can easily access SharePoint APIs, similarly, do we have the same for Java?

If yes, then please tell me more about it.
If not, then could you please tell me a workaround for this?